# page is not showing as expected in Wordpress page option

Tags: wordpress

Wanted to show traditional page layout for word press.

If i clicked edit page option then layout looks very weird. Please find the link below

[image: https://ibb.co/72NTqRv]

Please suggest. how to switch to traditional look and feel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the new Gutenberg Editor you are seeing which came with WP version 5.0. To avoid it, you can install the "Classic Editor" plugin, which will bring back the "old" editor (i.e. TinyMCE)